# Copying a file to all users on a workstation where the folder has a unique code pinned to user

Tags: powershell, file, copying

I'm trying to copy a config file into the Appdata\Local area so that it defaults software profile settings for each user on a workstation. I'm trying to get the script to be generic so that it works on multiple workstations. The folder I'm copying to is different for each workstation. On every workstation the name will be the same up until the unique code at the end. See the example code below for detail.

I cannot find the right powershell tag to copy to all users for some reason when I use * it returns the error of invalid characters. I also cannot work out a way of setting it to copy to a consistent named folder with its unique tag at the end. (The tag at the end is needed for the software to work.)

```
$Source = 'd:\ArcProInstallMedia\user.config' 
$Destination = 'c:\users\*\appdata\local\esri\ArcGisPro_StrongName_UNIQUE CODE NUMBER HERE \2.3.0.0'

Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Force
```

I expect the script to be able to copy the user config file from its default location on every workstation to every user profile on the workstation. I want this to work on multiple workstations so I do not have to edit the code every time I use it.

Comment: You can use wildcards in a source path, but not in a destination path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path with a wildcard with Get-ChildItem

```
$Destination = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\users\*\appdata\local\esri\ArcGisPro_StrongName_*\2.3.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple fix had me stumped for hours